# Android Array creation when a button is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

I need to create an automatic listview when a button was clicked. The user input two numbers e when the button was clicked, it generates a list from the the first number to the last number. When I debug the app, the console doesn't show me any error, but when i start it on my device and i click on the button, the app has an unexpected crash. I've tried to change the operations inside the onClick event. I try to do a sum of the two number and it work. The question is. Where is the mistake? It is the code.

```
package com.example.andre.thelist;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class part2 extends MainActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });*/

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gen);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {




        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), firsto.getClass().getName() + " " + result , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            EditText firste = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstn);
            EditText laste = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastn);
            String firsti = firste.getText().toString();
            String lasti = laste.getText().toString();
            int firsto = Integer.parseInt(firsti);
            int lastoo = Integer.parseInt(lasti);
            ListView listMod = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMod);
            List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();

            ArrayAdapter<Integer> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                    part2.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    lista);

            for (int i = firsto; i <= lastoo; i++) {
                lista.add(i);
            }

            listMod.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            listMod.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adattatore, final View componente, int pos, long id) {
                    final Integer numero = (Integer) adattatore.getItemAtPosition(pos);

                    //creo il ciclo di controllo valori
                    if (numero > 0) {
                        boolean isPrime = true;
                        for (int i = 2; i <= numero / 2; i++) {
                            if (numero % i == 0) {
                                isPrime = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (isPrime) {
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(part2.this).create();
                            alertDialog.setTitle("Yeah numero primo");
                            alertDialog.setMessage("Il numero " + numero + " è un numero primo!");
                            alertDialog.show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Il numero " + numero + " non è un numero primo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });

}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();

ArrayAdapter<Integer> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(part2.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    lista);
```

and: `adattatore.getItemAtPosition(pos);`should be `lista.get(pos)`

```
alertDialog.create().show();
```

OMG! You should refactor your code

Comment: OMG that work! Yeah, I know, now it works and I can start to refactor the code! Thanks for the help.